# Why is this lattice modular?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm reading Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, and he says every lattice with at most six elements is modular.  But what about the lattice below on the right? If $x,y$ are the two elements at the penultimate level, it seems $x\vee y :> x,y$ but $x \wedge y \not<: x,y$.  What am I missing?

[image: lattices]

Edit: Never mind, he said every *semimodular* lattice with $\leq 6$ elements is modular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a target to accept the answer, as the OP has answered his own question.

> Edit: Never mind, he said every *semimodular* lattice with $\ge 6$ elements is modular.